Resize last instance of an "instance on point" node to fit the base curve?
I'm pretty new to Geometry Nodes,
My goal is simple, i want to instantiate panels along a curve made of multiple segments.
I want the panels to have the same size except for the last one of each segment so that they cover exactly the length of each segment.
I managed to do it for a single segment by trimming it and resizing the instance on last point.
The problem is I can't reproduce if the base curve has multiple segments :
I managed to trim each segment thanks to the Spline Length node, but i can't use this output to resize the last instance of each segment (I read that the output is a field of values and can't be used as i thought)
Each segment has only two points (start and end, no subdivivion) if that can help.
Any idea how i can solve this problem ?
(edited the image to clarify)

Blend file


The problem is not clear based on the screenshot. Can you make a sketch of what you want to achieve? The last point of the curve is at the very end of the curve by definition, so if an object has its origin within its geometric center, its scale has to be exactly 0 in order to fit within the curve.

Here is one of the possible approaches:

Used the accumulate field to get the points distances.

I scaled the instances by ratio "points distance/panel length"




Update with the evenly sized instances:


update with the booleans:



Wow, thank you so much !
I see the last instance is scaled down and so are the panels undulations which is kind of a problem since I'd like them to be constant across the curve.
I'll try to understand your method and start from there.

Thanks a lot, that's a great solution.
However i'd prefer not to scale the instances, they will get varying lengths since they scale with the edges lengths.
I edited the screenshot to make it easier to understand I hope.

As the end segments vary and you want to keep the same wave scale, you cannot use instances anymore for these parts. Above is an update with the booleans involved.

Thank you very much for your time ! I tried to work with booleans too, it kinda worked but was a little buggy and didn't work well with angles. I wish there was a "cleaner" solution because the boolean computing makes the file a bit unresponsive (at least on my computer). That's why I abandoned this solution but it's not really a problem
Thank you again, that was very helpful !

Another approach could be to duplicate the curves and trim them from the other side "by the all even panels lengths sum" - "just to keep the trims" and then fill these short corner/end curves with small "one wave panel" instances and scale these just a very bit. (maybe this was what you wanted to do in your original question?) you can combine the methods from above to achieve this.

Yes I think it should work, very good idea, trying it right now

It's working just fine ! Just need to refine the instanced mesh to make it tilable. Thanks !
